# How to play a youtube video in swift using AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, swift-playground

How to play a youtube video in swift using AVPlayer?

I am using the below code to play a youtube video but nothing happens in avplayer. It remains blank.

```
var urlstring = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMba_c-VSkI"
var url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
var av:AVPlayerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AVPlayerViewController
av.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
```

Answer (score 3):

AVPlayer only plays movie files, and YouTube videos aren't directly exposed as movie files at their URL. You can handle youtube videos in your own WebView.

You can use IFrame Player API.

Answer (score 2):

The url you are using is not the url to the video, it is the url to a webpage which has the video embedded.  There are tools out there that can help you get the actual url of the video file.

Comment: The embed url is also a url to a page/player.  Youtube doesn't make the actual media files url readily available, not to mention it exists in many formats and sizes.  Again, if you are wanting to stream a video with an AVPlayer, you're going to need to have an actual media file location, not a webpage.  If you are wanting to show youtube videos, you might want to look at their iOS SDK/API

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a like [YoutubeParser](https://github.com/movielala/YoutubeSourceParserKit) to get it to work. But please note this will go against Youtube's T&C